# bad operand types for binary operator '-'

Tags: java

I'm getting an error message on line "Math.sqrt(Math.pow ((x2)-(x1), 2)+Math.pow((y2)-(y1), 2));" and I can't figure what the problem is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;

public class Distance

{

   public static void main(String[] args)

   { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter x1: ");
    String x1=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println ("Enter y1: ");
    String y1=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println ("Enter x2: ");
    String x2=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println ("Enter y2: ");
    String y2=scan.nextLine();

    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow ((x2)-(x1), 2)+Math.pow((y2)-(y1), 2));

    System.out.println ("The distance between the points is: "+ distance);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` does not exist for type `String`.

You probably entered `int` values that you can read doing:

```
int x1 = scan.nextInt();
// etc
```

Answer (score 5):

You're subtracting `String`s, not `int`s.

Parse the `String`s with `Integer.parseInt(x1)`.

Comment: Or just use `Scanner#nextInt()`.

Comment: I'm gonna sound like an idiot, but where would I put that in the code?